# How to give Node.js user permissions to write to the project folder in Docker container runnig Alpine?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Say I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM image 
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
USER node
CMS [npm, start]
```

When the app starts, it apparently needs to write to the node_modules directory. However, since the modules are installed by the root user, the node user does not have write permissions in this directory.

What would be the most orthodox method to address this in a production  environment?

To address this, I have tried:

1. Change owner or permissions of the directory. However, this takes too long. I aborted this approach after 400 second of execution of the run command. 400 seconds of build time is ridiculous for my small application.
2. Remove `USER node` from the DOCKERFILE. This works, but I doubt it would be acceptable in production.

Comment: Just... don't install the modules as root? First switch users to the one that's going to be running Node, then run `npm install`. And make sure you've configured that user to have read/write/execute access to the project dir. As for "that takes too long": show what you did, because that sounds like you may have simply done that part wrong.

Comment: I'd try to fix the bug or security issue where something in the application is trying to overwrite its own code.  Do you know _what_ is trying to write to `node_modules`, and why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Switch to non-root user `node` prior to create working directory.
2. Change owner when copy file/directory from host to image.
3. Run `npm install` by user `node` but `root`.

```
FROM image
USER node
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown==node:node . .
RUN npm install
CMD [npm, start]
```